# Unable to view Code coverage results in VS 2019

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, code-coverage, xunit

I have written test cases using xUnit and Moq for .Net Core Unit test project.Unable to view code coverage results in VS 2019. I am getting screen as below

[image]

[image]

Few times it shows results and few times it wont show results. Restarting VS didn't helped.

How to resolve this.